# Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{Z}$ is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question states:

prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{Z}$ is denumerable.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: If a set is denumerable, then any subset of it is denumerable. It is not important  to explicitly produce the bijection between the given set and the natural numbers, an injection will do, and the composition of the bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb N$, and the inclusion map of the given set into the rationals, gives an injection into the natural numbers, that suffices to prove denumerability of the given set.

Comment: @DanRust    Well, I would think that even if we remove the integers we would still be left with a denumerable set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb Q - \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$. $\mathbb Q$ is denumerable, and so is any subset of it. More generally, any subset of a denumerable set is denumerable.

Comment: We can just use the theorem of subsets of a countable set?

Comment: If you've proven that subsets of denumerable sets are denumerable, then yes. Why would you not be able to? If not, you should try to do so; it's not difficult. People here should be able to help if you run into difficulty after doing so.

Comment: I have proved this before, and okay I just didn't think to sat that Q-Z is a subset of Q. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam Sure. Whenever you get stuck trying to show a result, it's a good rule of thumb to look over previous results you already know to see if any of them will help you with the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
  First, do you see why
$$
|\mathbb{Q} - \mathbb{Z}| \le | \mathbb{Q}|?
$$
Next, try to prove that
$$
|\mathbb{Z} | \le |\mathbb{Q} - \mathbb{Z}|
$$
by using the injective function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} - \mathbb{Z}$, $f(x) = x + \frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb Z$ is infinite (it contains the elements $n+\frac{1}{2}$ for all integers $n \in \mathbb Z$) and is subset of a denumerable set ($\mathbb Q$), so it is itself denumerable.

Answer (score 0):

$$\biggl\{\dfrac1n\;\bigg\vert\; n\in\mathbf N, \,n>1\biggr\}$$
is denumerable, and contained in $\mathbf Q\smallsetminus\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Except for $n=1$ :-)

Comment: OK, you win ;o)